# Exception #0: Warning: include(/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml)

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, permissions, custom-theme, parent-child-theme

I am getting this error when I try to open to product catalog page in Magento 2.4.3 Custom theme?

> Exception #0 (Exception): Warning:
> include(/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml):
> failed to open stream: Permission denied in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php
> on line 71

I set permission also using root.

cd `/var/www/html/<magento install directory>`
find var generated vendor `pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +`

find var generated vendor `pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +`

`chown -R :www-data .` # Ubuntu

`chmod u+x bin/magento`

Kindly can you please help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the ***attribute.phtml*** is not included because of the permission issue. In such a case, I run the below command.

`sudo chmod  777 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml.`

if it works then you need to add a web user to your apache/Nginx web user group. Also please reset permission for attribute.phtml and try to set proper permission again.

You could also move ***attribute.phtml*** file to your theme directory to debug the issue.

Hope the above instruction will resolve your issue.

Comment: Instead sudo chmod  777. Can I give permission with 644 or 755?

Comment: try first "sudo chmod 777." if it works then reset permission with 644 and 755 and set ownership of attribute.phtml file too.

Comment: I tried using this..still not working
sudo chmod  777 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml.